# Face Detection Neural Network Training Data (databases, number of faces etc)

Tags: neural-network, face-detection, training-data

I'm creating a face detection program using neural networks, and looking for some reliable training sets.  I'm aware there's various sets around the web, but I've not idea how good they are.  Any ideas where to start?

Comment: try flickr search, or google images with a good keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A certainly entertaining way would be to get faces from google image search.

But seriously: http://vision.ai.uiuc.edu/mhyang/face-detection-survey.html

Comment: Most of the links on that page are broken... I managed to get the MIT CBCL database, but there's a rather a lot of images, and I'm not sure it's really necessary...? Or is it? Plus some of those images aren't cropped very well.

Comment: the Yale faces work too - ftp://plucky.cs.yale.edu/CVC/pub/images/yalefacesB/TarSets/ - sorry for the dead links

Answer (score 2):

[CMU has some nice face datasets](http://vasc.ri.cmu.edu/idb/html/face/index.html), especially if you're trying to detect the location of the face, and not only whether its present or not.

[Essex university facial images collection](http://cswww.essex.ac.uk/mv/allfaces/index.html) is another commonly used dataset.